# HP Pavilion dv6t Quad Edition (dv6tqe) Antenna Configuration?

Tags: hp-pavilion, antenna

HP website does not disclose the technical details about the wi-fi card on dv6tqe. Can anyone tell me about its antenna config, i.e. 2x2 or 1x1?

Comment: @Moab an owner of dv6tqe will be able to check the model of their wifi card.

Comment: @Moab It is not a complete model number but a series (and I suspect that they use the similar wifi card on this product line since there is no specific options at customization). Look [here](http://www.shopping.hp.com/series/category/notebooks/dv6tqe_series/3/computer_store;).

Comment: You can add bluetooth which could change the brand of card, I looked up that particular config you linked to at HP PartSurfer, it shows it to have been built with a "802.11bgn Int HMC 1x2 RP WLAN" card.....http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?searchText=A1T70UA

Comment: @Moab Thank you so much! This is what I need. I did not know HP has such a convenient website. (I cannot vote up your comment, so you wanna submit this as an answer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up [that particular config](http://www.shopping.hp.com/series/category/notebooks/dv6tqe_series/3/computer_store;) (dv6t) you linked to at HP PartSurfer, [it shows it to have been built with a "802.11bgn Int HMC 1x2 RP WLAN"](http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?searchText=A1T70UA)

I don't guarantee this is what you will get, HP can change hardware specs at any time but they should also change the Product Number (A1T70UA) when they do, so be sure the one you order is the same product number as the one researched on PartSurfer.

Product number is different than Model number on HP notebooks, Product Number will reflect the hardware used to build that particular Model of notebook when using PartSurfer.